# derivative of convolution of a distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis

I want to prove that the convolution of a distribution is a $C^1$-function i.e. I want to prove that $u \ast \phi \in C^1$. I want to use the usual definition of derivative. Can anyone please help me with that.

Here`s what I have:

$$ \frac {u\ast \phi (x+te_i-a)-u\ast \phi (x-a)}{t} = \frac{\langle  u,\phi(x+te_i-a)\rangle-\langle u,\phi (x-a) \rangle}{t} $$ $$= \langle u, \frac{\phi(x-(a-te_i))-\phi (x-a)}{-t} \rangle$$
and this converges to $$- \langle u,\frac { \partial \phi}{\partial x_i}(x-a) \rangle$$

then I have a note saying that we need to do it in a uniform way, show that the difference quotient converge to derivative in the topology of $\mathcal D (\mathbb R)$. I seriously don`t know what does this mean:(.

Thanks

Comment: How far have you come yourself?

Comment: I added what I have in the question.

Comment: How has the convolution of a distribution and an ordinary function been defined in the course?

Comment: same definitions as in folland book. There are 2 definitions.

Comment: If $F$ is a distribution, then $\lt F \ast \psi, \phi \gt = \lt F, \phi \ast \widetilde \psi \gt$ such that $\widetilde \psi = \psi (-x)$

Comment: Can you show that $F*\phi$ is continuous and that $(F*\phi)' = F*\phi'$ (using only distributional definitions)? If so, then conclude that also $(F*\phi)^{(k)}$ is continuous for all $k=1, 2, \ldots$, so $F*\phi \in C^\infty$.

Comment: There's no definition like $(u*\psi)(x) = \langle u(y), \psi(x-y) \rangle$? Then you directly get that $u*\psi$ is a function and can use the classical definition of derivative.

Comment: yes, you are right but as far as I know my prof. used the definition that I wrote not this one you wrote. I feel kind of confused now.

Comment: Now I'm home from work and have opened my Folland, Real Analysis. Part of Proposition (8.44) is similar to what you shall show. There the definition I wrote is used to show $F * \psi \in C^\infty$.

Comment: An answer to "show that the difference quotient converge to derivative":  
You need to show that there is a compact set $K$ such that $\phi_t(x) := t^{-1} \left( \phi(x+te_i-a) - \phi(x-a) \right)$ has support in $K$ and that the uniform norms of all its derivatives tend to $0$ as $t \to 0$.